# Как поменять стиль шрифта меню в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

[image: 1]

Стиль шрифта изменился на italic, все элементы стали под наклоном. Как это можно изменить? `В Settings -> Appearance` не нашёл

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File -> settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance -> Override default fonts by (not recommended) -> и выбрать шрифт и размер